# Reference a hidden value in a form using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am new to web development

I have PHP delete function that I want to use to delete rows from a database table.

```
if($form_no==="delete" && isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['form_no']))
{
    switch ($_POST['form_no']) {
        case 1:$table="employees"; break;

        default:break;
    }
    $query="DELETE from ".$table." where id=".$_POST['id'];
    mysql_query($query)or die( ' '.mysql_error().'  '.$query);
    $message='deleted';
    switch ($_POST['form_no']) {
        case 1:manageEmployees($message);break;

        default:break;
    }

}
```

here is one of the forms that I am displaying on screen

```
<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Password</th><th>Phone   number</th></tr>   
       <tr><td><input type="hidden" id="form_no" name="form_no" value="1"></td></tr>

<tr><td><input type="text" name="firstname[]" id="firstname"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lastname[]" id="lastname"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email[]" id="email"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="password[]" id="password"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone_no[]" id="phone_no"></td>
    <td><button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Add Employee</button></td>
<td><button type="button" name="delete" class="delete" value=21>Delete Employee</button></td></tr>
    <td><p><p></td>
    </tr>
```

I am trying to get access to other values in a form. When the button is clicked I can get the ID I am looking for as it is the value of the button. What I really want to do is get the value of the hidden field and find out in which for the delete button is pressed.

I can not use find elementById as the delete buttons are not unique nor are the forms. I am trying to use `$(this).parents().parents('#form_no').val()`, however this returns undefined.

I know that it must be possible to do but I am not getting any closer, many thanks in advance if any one can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You're close. Element id's **should** be unique. Change them to classes and you should be fine.

Comment: Just wrote this up for a similar question, maybe can give you some pointers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260831/jquery-parsing-html-into-json/18261290#18261290

Comment: and also, SQL injections.

Comment: how do you get sql injections when the id is produced by the server from a db, not the user? or am I missing something big here?

Comment: Just because the inputs are produced by the server and put in a form doesn't mean a moderately intelligent user cannot manipulate them in the url or via some kind of tool that lets them manipulate the HTML.

Comment: Please use PDO and prepared queries to avoid SQL injection. Also, you can easily inject `$_POST` values if a user just creates a fake form and submits it to your script. [xkcd Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: It is post but in light of that I will change it.